# Is it correct to rewrite $A+AB$ as $A(I+B)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If $A$, $B$ are square matrices, can you rewrite the equation $A+AB$ as $A(I+B)$?

Can you also write $A+AB$ as $A(1+B)$?

If so, how can it be, since $(1+B) \neq (I+B)$?

Comment: You can write this only when  $A$ and $B$ are $1\times 1$ matrices (i.e. just scalars). Otherwise $1+B$ does not make sense. However some authors use $1$ to denote the identity matrix $I$.

Comment: @KaboMurphy so A(I+B) is correct?

Comment: Yes,  $A+AB=A(I+B)$.

Comment: @KaboMurphy thank you.

Comment: Assuming $A$ and $B$ are matrices over some field and $I$ means the identity matrix, then yes it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in the endomorphism ring $\operatorname{End}(V)$ of some vector space $V$. If you want to make clear that $I$ is the identity element of $\operatorname{End}(V)$, you can write $\operatorname{Id}$ or even $\operatorname{Id}_V$, as in
$$A + AB = A \big( \operatorname{Id} + B \big)$$